# Can SQL Injection happen when using Knockout.js?

Tags: json, ajax, knockout.js

I am required to demonstrate SQL Injection in a website, however my website is using knockout.js data-bind to receive AJAX object with type POST and dataType JSON.

An example are:

```
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<div data-bind="value:  details().Name" />
<script> 
    ko.applyBindings();
</script>
```

Can SQL Injection occur in such form submission? If so, how can it happen? Can you provide an example as to how the input will be like to delete all rows?

e.g. normal SQL Injection will be

```
a'; DROP TABLE users;
```

How can this happen in my website?

Comment: *"I am required to demonstrate SQL Injection in a website"* The technologies you use on the website are irrelevant: Just send a custom-crafted POST, completely bypassing KO and your JavaScript code. It's the **server** code that needs to be invulnerable to SQL-Injection; there's nothing whatsoever your client-code can do to prevent it.

Comment: As a side note, I prefer to put in place the corresponding server side validations for those at the client side...

Answer (score 3):

SQL injection must be prevented on the server-side.

Whatever happens on the client side is irrelevant.

Security audit companies might use your interface but they will more likely use other tools to send HTTP queries to your site, thus bypassing your frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Whether your website is using Knockout or any other front-end framework is completely unrelated to whether it has SQL injection vulnerabilities. Whatever SQL queries your application is running are being generated by the API your front-end is connecting to.

In order to properly test the API for SQL injection vulnerabilities you will need to manually craft custom HTTP requests with your own JSON payload to try and identify if any of the fields are vulnerable to SQL injection. This is because your API likely has many more inputs than are exposed directly via your UI, and so by testing the UI you are not getting full coverage of your system.